# Update sql via php form mysql error occured

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$meldning = $_POST['meldning'];
$ebruker = $_POST['bruker'];

$sql = "UPDATE Crew ".
   "SET meldning = $meldning ".
   "WHERE bruker = $bruker" ;
```

the problem i have is when i try to update this from my php script it says

> Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

EDIT: Resolved HALF of it now i get : >Could not update data: Unknown column 'tobias' in 'where clause'

Comment: *"Could not update data: Unknown column 'tobias' in 'where clause'"* - There you go, your query failed and you don't have a column called "tobias". You'll need to be a bit more specific as to what you're wanting to do here, including your DB schema and what's coming from your form/POSTs. At this point, *it's anybody's guess!*

Comment: You may also let the people know as to which MySQL API you're using to connect with. Right now, you've a variable that doesn't match. This, making it THAT much harder to give you a definite and concrete answer. *Good luck!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$meldning = $_POST['meldning'];
$ebruker = $_POST['bruker'];

$sql = "UPDATE Crew
   SET meldning = '$meldning'
   WHERE bruker = '$bruker' " ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add mysql_real_escape_string() to escape bad chars and  like ' for mysql and add quotes in sql query

```
$meldning = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['meldning']);
    $ebruker = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bruker']);

$sql = "UPDATE Crew ".
   "SET meldning = '$meldning' ".
   "WHERE bruker = '$bruker'" ;
```

Comment: You're assuming the OP is using the deprecated `mysql_*()` API.  If he's using a later API your attempt at preventing SQL injection will fail.

Comment: I did that now i get this error     Could not update data: Unknown column 'tobias' in 'where clause'

Dont worry im not worried that there will be injection nothing to find in my db

Comment: you mistake "WHERE bruker = ' $bruker '"  with    $ebruker in the top change with  $bruker = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bruker']);

Comment: Yeah the mistake was ebruker the "e" was a typo but now i get another error

Comment: @LucaOlivieri `mysql` extension will be removed from `PHP` at the end of the year, use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Please never trust the user sended data like POST or GET. Always check the value and escape. I suggest you to use the PDO. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data
$title = 'PHP Pattern';
$author = 'Imanda';
$id = 3;
// query
$sql = "UPDATE Crew 
        SET meldning=?
        WHERE bruker=?";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($_POST['meldning'],$_POST['bruker']));
```